# html - positioning an img right to a relative div

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have a center div and a simple problem...
I don't know how to place a image right to it relative(!) like this:
[image]

```
<div class="text_middle">
    <span class="volat_text">App</span>
    <div id="sport_dropdown">
        <span id="sport">Test</span>
    </div>
</div>
<img id="arrow_down" src="img/arrow_down.png">
```

Here is the code: http://codepen.io/lalaluki/pen/pNNYpZ

Does somebody knows a trick?

Comment: The image can't be put inside the "text_middle" div?

Comment: why don't you create a centered div for both your original div and the image, then just organize them inside the already centered div anyway you want

Comment: no look at the description under.

Answer (score 0):

You can place something like `<span>&#x25BE;</span>` inside your `.text_middle` element. I used the html symbol code for a downside triangle because you did not provide the image in your pen example. But you can try it with an image or glyphicon instead.

```
<div class="text_middle">
    <span class="volat_text">App</span>
    <div id="sport_dropdown">
        <span id="sport">Test</span>
    </div>
    <span>&#x25BE;</span>
</div>
```

See the pen **[here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dOOrQX)**

Comment: yeah i know... But I want the div "text_middle" centered and not the dropdown... The dropdown should be right near the centered div...

Comment: yes, you div `.text_middle` is centered. The dropdown is part of it.

Comment: Yes and I don't want that the dropdown is part of. I want that the dropdown right aligned ...

Comment: than why did you put it inside `text_middle`?

Answer (score 0):

```css
.vertical_align{
  vertical-align:middle;
  }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div id="top_bar">

<div class="text_middle">
          <span class="volat_text">App</span>
          <div id="sport_dropdown">
            <span id="sport">Test</span>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down vertical_align" ></span>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Try this.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would apply `float:right` to the image:

```
#arrow_down {
    float:right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to change your HTML Structure to achieve this quickly. Add image inside '.text-middle' div

```
<div class="text_middle">
          <span class="volat_text">App</span>
          <div id="sport_dropdown">
            <span id="sport">Test</span>
          </div>
          <img id="arrow_down" src="img/arrow_down.png">
        </div>
```

Add vertical align middle to your image

```
#arrow_down {
vertical-align: middle;}
```

Hope this will help you